# Decomposing representations of finite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, modular-representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, $p$ a prime number. We denote by $\mathbb{F}_p$ the field of cardinality $p$. Let $V$ be an infinite dimensional representation of $G$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Must there be $G$-invariant, proper subspaces $U,W \leq V$ such that $U + W = V$?

I do not require the sum to be direct. The question should be equivalent to asking:

Must $V$ have a nontrivial decomposable image?

I am able to prove this if $p$ does not divide $|G|$ by applying Maschke's theorem to decompose $V$ into a direct sum of finite-dimensional irreducible subrepresentations. Even if in general the answer is negative, I would like to know about additional cases in which the conclusion holds, to say:

Under what conditions on $G$ can we find such subspaces?

Interesting cases can be abelian, solvable or any other "nice" classes of groups.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am not sure that I follow Rickard's argument, but here is a direct proof. Given an infinite dimensional module $V$ (over an arbitrary field.) for a finite group $G$, I want to argue first that there exists a proper $G$-submodule $U$ with finite codimension. Let $X < V$ be an arbitrary proper subspace with finite codimension. Then
$U = \bigcap_{g \in G} X^g$ is $G$-invariant and is an intersection of finitely many proper subspaces with finite codimension, so is proper and has finite codimension. Next, let
$Y \subseteq V$ be a finite dimensional subspace such that $U + Y = V$. Let
$W = \sum_{g \in G} Y^g$. Then $W$ is $G$-invariant and finite dimensional, so $W < V$. Also, $U + W = V$, as wanted.

Answer (score 13):

Yes. In fact, $V$ has an infinite dimensional semisimple quotient, which is decomposable since any simple $\mathbb{F}_pG$-module is a quotient of $\mathbb{F}_pG$ and so is finite-dimensional.

Let $V'=\operatorname{rad}(V)=V.\operatorname{rad}(\mathbb{F}_pG)$. Then $V/V'$ is infinite dimensional if $V$ is, and is semisimple. (It's infinite dimensional since any epimorphism from a finite dimensional projective module to $V/V'$ would lift to an epimorphism to $V$.)

For finitely generated profinite groups, as asked about in comments, there are counterexamples. I asked a former colleague, John MacQuarrie, who's worked on modular representations of profinite groups, and the following example is based on his answer (although any errors introduced in translating it into terms I understand are my own work).

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$ with countable basis $\{e_1,e_2,\dots\}$, and let $\mathbb{Z}$ act on $V$ by letting a generator send $e_i$ to $e_{i-1}+e_i$ for $i>1$ and $e_1$ to $e_1$. If $q$ is a power of $p$ with $q>i$, then $q$ fixes $e_i$, so the action extends to a discrete action of the $p$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$. It easy to check that the span $V_n=\langle e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n\rangle$ is a submodule for any $0\leq n$, and that these are the only proper submodules. This module can be more naturally described as the Pontryagin dual of the regular representation of the profinite group algebra $\mathbb{F}_p[[\mathbb{Z}_p]]$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can this be generalized to the case of profinite $G$ somehow (In this case I assume that $V$ is a discrete $G$-module)? I think that I can construct some counterexample in the general case but what if, say, $G$ is finitely generated? Maybe more restrictions should be put on $G$ in order to make this true in the profinite case?

Comment: I don't follow this. What does "and is semisimple" at the end mean?  Projectives need not be semisimple.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: Sorry, I edited the sentence by putting in an explanation in the middle, making it confusing. I meant $V/V'$ is infinite dimensional and semisimple (with an explanation of why it's infinite dimensional in the middle). I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: @JeremyRickard, why must an epimorphism from a projective module lift to an epimorphism?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: By projectivity it lifts to a map to $V$. If that map is not an epimorphism and has image $V''$, then $V/V''$ is non-zero and so has a simple quotient, but every map from $V$ to a simple module factors through $V/\operatorname{rad}(V)$.

Comment: @JeremyRickard I suppose that your assertion that V/V' is semisimple means that it is a direct sum of simples, but I don't see why that holds, even if the radical is trivial. Doesn't proof of semisimplicty require assuming that the module is finitely generated. I don't see why your argument shows that V has a simple quotient or why it answers the original question. Can you explain?

Comment: Fg is not needed to give that modules over a semisimple ring are direct sums of simples. But I think fg is need to guarantee a maximal proper submodule.

Comment: $V/V'$ is a module for $\mathbb{F}_pG/\operatorname{rad}(\mathbb{F}_pG)$, which is a semisimple algebra, and all modules (even infinitely generated) for semisimple algebras are direct sums of simple modules.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Right. Every module over a semisimple algebra is semisimple by a Zorn argument, and that implies that over a semisimple algebra, every nonzero module has a simple quotient. I see now that that does answer the original question using the fact that V/V' is not simple because it is infinite dimensional.

Comment: @Pablo: I've edited my answer to add an answer to your question about profinite groups.

Comment: Great! It answers my question on the profinite case. Maybe you know what happens if you replace $\mathbb{F}_p$ by $\mathbb{Z}_p$ before applying Pontryagin's duality? What I mean is that I take a finitely generated profinite group $G$, and a profinite $G$-module $V$, which is a power of $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Must there be two nontrivial disjoint $G$-submodules? Your example answers this question in the negative in the $\mathbb{F}_p$ case. Dose the analogous example works for the $\mathbb{Z}_p$ case? Maybe there is another counterexample instead?